# Sequelize save/create method only works at first time on CRUD app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, es6-promise

**General issue:**  
I've been having a hard time trying to build a simple CRUD app using JavaScript + node JS + express + sequelize (MySQL).

**Contextualization about the project**  
My CRUD app is being developed to manage students from a particular English teacher. 
There are some table models created: Alunos - *English: Students*, Boletos - *English: Pay Order*, Aulas - *English: Classes*, and others that are not mandatory to explain for this issue for now.

**Specific issue:**  
There is a post route that takes some of my body contents and inserts a new student to table "Alunos". After the row containing student data is created, I need to create registries for "Boletos", it would be 12 month of Pay Orders registered into this table. There are two problems with this part: the first I register a student, it works fine, **but I could not get the auto-increment id generated by the model to insert in the foreign key "AlunoId", so the foreign key for "Boletos" table is set to null.**  The other problem is that the both entries (1 into "Alunos" and 12 into "Boletos") works fine at first, to registry the first student, **but after the page is refreshed and I try to registry another student, node JS throws an error:**

```
(node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
    at Query.formatError (D:\ProgramacaoEstudos\ProjetoCRUD2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:242:16)
    at Query.run (D:\ProgramacaoEstudos\ProjetoCRUD2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:77:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async D:\ProgramacaoEstudos\ProjetoCRUD2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:619:16
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.insert (D:\ProgramacaoEstudos\ProjetoCRUD2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:749:21)
    at async model.save (D:\ProgramacaoEstudos\ProjetoCRUD2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3954:35)
    at async D:\ProgramacaoEstudos\ProjetoCRUD2\routes\admin.js:101:30
(node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

**Code:**

1. Models - Alunos:

```js
// Create Aluno table model and export to be called to other file
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Aluno = sequelize.define('Aluno', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    surname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    birth: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    mobile_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    residential_address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    profession: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    company: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    num_classes_week: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    classes_day: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    classes_time: {
      type: DataTypes.TIME,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    starts_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    discount: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    due_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  Aluno.associate = (models) => {
    Aluno.hasMany(models.Aula, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    });
  };

  Aluno.associate = (models) => {
    Aluno.hasMany(models.Boleto, {
      onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
    });
  };

  Aluno.associate = (models) => {
    Aluno.hasMany(models.Assiste_Aula, {
      onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
    });
  };

  return Aluno;
};
```

2. Models - Boletos:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Boleto = sequelize.define('Boleto', {
        value: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            allowNull: false
        },
        due_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })

    Boleto.associate = (models) => {
        Boleto.belongsTo(models.Aluno, {
            foreignKey: 'AlunoId'  
        })
    }

    return Boleto
}
```

Routes - Post - registry:

```
// Post Routes
router.post('/realizado', async (req, res) => {
  // Create Aluno
  // Compute values of some attributes
  var cls_day = req.body.classes_day;
  var num_cls = cls_day.length;

  var dias;
  for (let i = 0; i < num_cls; i++) {
    if (i + 1 < num_cls) {
      dias += cls_day[i] + '-';
    } else {
      dias += cls_day[i];
    }
  }

  // Instantiate Aluno model
  const aluno = db.Aluno.build({
    name: req.body.name,
    surname: req.body.surname,
    birth: req.body.birth,
    phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
    mobile_number: req.body.mobile_number,
    email: req.body.email,
    residential_address: req.body.residential_address,
    profession: req.body.profession,
    company: req.body.company,
    num_classes_week: num_cls,
    classes_day: dias,
    classes_time: req.body.classes_time,
    starts_at: req.body.starts_at,
    value: req.body.value,
    discount: req.body.discount,
    due_date: req.body.due_date,
  });

  // Insert into database
  const newAluno = await aluno.save();

  // Create boleto
  var objList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var firstDt = new Date(req.body.due_date);

    // Compute current date
    var dt = firstDt.setMonth(firstDt.getMonth() + i);
    //dt.setDate(dt.getMonth() + i)
    // Build boleto object
    var boleto;
    boleto = db.Boleto.build({
      value: req.body.value,
      due_date: dt,
      alunoId: newAluno.id,
    });

    objList.push(boleto);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++) {
    try {
      await objList[i].save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  res.render('realizado');
});
```

**Final Considerations:** 
Since I'm new with node JS and JavaScript I didn't know about the Promises and the syntactic sugar `await/async`. I've already studied with a bunch of videos and I think I got the basics concepts about it, but I'm not being able to apply it to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use `db.Aluno.create()` or set `db.Aluno.build({...}, { isNewRecord: true })` to let Sequelize know it's an insert and not a record with a primary key value of 0. Your DB likely sees the ID of 0 and either inserts it or sets it to 1, either way you will get a conflict on the second insert.

It's also a good idea to wrap your router/controller code in a `try/catch` to handle any errors. Use a transaction that is passed to all your queries/inserts so that you can roll them all back if there is an error at any stage - const transaction = await sequelize.transaction(); const aluno = await db.Aluno.create({...}, { transaction });. Commit at the end with await `transaction.commit()` or in the catch block roll back with `await transaction.rollback()`.

Don't use await in a for loop - its the same as blocking for each call which is inefficient and slow. Instead you can pass an array of promises to Promise.all() and resolve them concurrently.... `objList.push(boleto.save());` (don't await here) and then `await Promise.all(objList);`.

Some last notes - it's good to use `const` when a variable won't change and `let` when it might to make your results more consistent. You should also try to have an explicit return from arrow functions.

Here is your code with the changes applied.

```js
// Post Routes
router.post('/realizado', async (req, res) => {
  // we may or may not be able to create a transaction, so use let
  let transaction;
  try {
    // start a new transaction an pass to all the create() calls
    transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

    // Compute values of some attributes
    var cls_day = req.body.classes_day;
    var num_cls = cls_day.length;

    var dias;
    for (let i = 0; i < num_cls; i++) {
      if (i + 1 < num_cls) {
        dias += cls_day[i] + '-';
      } else {
        dias += cls_day[i];
      }
    }

    // Create Aluno model, use const since it won't change
    const aluno = await db.Aluno.create(
      {
        name: req.body.name,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        birth: req.body.birth,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        mobile_number: req.body.mobile_number,
        email: req.body.email,
        residential_address: req.body.residential_address,
        profession: req.body.profession,
        company: req.body.company,
        num_classes_week: num_cls,
        classes_day: dias,
        classes_time: req.body.classes_time,
        starts_at: req.body.starts_at,
        value: req.body.value,
        discount: req.body.discount,
        due_date: req.body.due_date,
      },
      {
        // use the transaction
        transaction,
      }
    );

    // Create boleto insert promise array
    // Use const because we will be adding items, but into the same const array
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const firstDt = new Date(req.body.due_date);
      // put the promise into the promises array
      promises.push(
        // the create call here will start the insert but not wait for it to complete
        db.Boleto.create(
          {
            value: req.body.value,
            due_date: firstDt.setMonth(firstDt.getMonth() + i),
            alunoId: aluno.id,
          },
          {
            // use the transaction so we can rollback if there are errors
            transaction,
          }
        )
      );
    }

    // await the result of all the boleto inserts
    await Promise.all(promises);

    // no errors, we can commit the transaction
    await transaction.commit();

    return res.render('realizado');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (transaction) {
      await transaction.rollback;
    }
    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me. Now the code is a lot cleaner and more understandable. But I still cannot register another student after I inserted the first one with current pay orders (it worked but the foreign key is still null for Boletos table). Do you think this could be a issue in the server configurations? I really can't understand why it wouldn't register the second student, given the first was inserted succesfully. When I delete the records of both tables, Alunos and Boletos, the app accepts the first registry again, but fails on the second one. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: sorry, foreign key set to null is my mistake. I was using the name of the field as "alunoId", but in fact it is "AlunoId", now this part worked fine. But the other error, which doesn't allow me to register more than one student, is still happening.

Comment: Man, I did something that worked for my problem, but I don't understand why the way I was doing was wrong in this part. The only thing I did was to take off the `unique` constraint when defining the Aluno model, I was using it for mobile number. Can you imagine why would it happen?  Since I was not regitering the same student, therefore I was not inserting an existing mobile number.

Comment: @caio.valente14 I missed the `unique` there. If I had to guess it is getting set to an empty string instead of null? The `try/catch` should help figure out the error. You can use a `set(value)` function on that column to check if it is an empty string and only set it if it's not as another idea.